# How should I count the number of launches of an applications in android

Tags: android

i can pick all installed application using below code :

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List Runningtasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

but i want launch count of each application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use polling the current application in the foreground
by asking the current running task.

```
int currentUidInFront = 0;
    while(true)
    {
    ActivityManager actMan = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> runningApps = actMan.getRunningTasks(1024);
    RunningTaskInfo runningTask = runningApps.get(0);
    int uidInFront = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(runningTask.topActivity.getPackageName(),1).uid;

    //chack if the current application is changed
    if(currentUidInFront != uidInFront)
    {
       currentUidInFront = uidInFront;
       Log.i("Changed running application",runningTask.topActivity.flattenToShortString());
    }  
  sleep(1000);
}
```

hope this helped. enjoy